# Does anyone know of any VS2010/2008 Project Templates for PRISM

Tags: prism

this I guess is similar to the MVVM templates - but does anyone know if VS2010 Project Templates exist for PRISM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are for Visual Studio 2010

http://blogs.msdn.com/dphill/archive/2010/03/25/prism-template-pack-for-visual-studio-2010.aspx